# Asp.net MVC Routing Problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

how many methods for adding style sheets in a page using Asp.net MVC

Comment: We will you don't need to have pls help in the title. It's what we do here =)

Comment: Another question with "pls help" in the title?

Comment: pls help ppl write better question titles. By editing their questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute links to css instead of relative (eg `/Content/site.css"` instead of `"../Content/site.css"`). Also you may use `Html.Stylesheet("~/Content/site.css")` extension (in MvcContrib library) to specify a stylesheet.

Answer (score 3):

Wherever you're specifying the CSS for your details page instead of a relative path e.g.

```
<link href="../../Content/CSS/details.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

try using the content helper and specifying a virtual path instead

```
<link href="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/CSS/details.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

It seems that the site is having trouble loading getting to the CSS file based on a relative link.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem not getting the right CSS? If so, then I would check your Details.aspx file and make sure the link to the CSS is the right path. Most likely, your Details.aspx file got moved into a new subdirectory or into another directory, thus making the relative paths between the aspx file and the CSS file different.

I would check the page source from the browser and look to see what the path to the CSS file is. The way I would solve the problem would be to modify the aspx file to use a fully-qualified path to the css file. Make sure that works. Then try changing the full path to use relative path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when working through an example in an MVC book, it mentioned something about the '~' character only working because the `<head>` tag has the `runat="server"` attribute on it. So, I tried adding the runat attribute to the link tag itself, as seen below, and it worked:

```
<link runat="server" href="~/Content/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```